# How do I improve Redux's performance when updating fast-moving UI state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, redux

The details of my problem involve me integrating a D3 force graph with my redux state.  Each `tick` update dispatches an action to update a position collection in my redux state.  These positions are then merged with node data and use to update my visualization.  React handles the DOM and D3 is used basically just to calculate forces, collision detection, etc.

I'm finding it difficult/impossible to maintain a smooth experience for the user using this design pattern.  Locally on my laptop, I'm getting ~117ms between actions, well below 60fps (16ms between actions).

I've tried to simplify and streamline my middleware as much as possible to reduce latency.

What other strategies can I employ to get better update time using redux?  Or am I trying to do something Redux was never meant to do?

Comment: What type(s) of middleware are you using? You can look into `redux-saga`

Comment: Not sure how redux saga will help? We have a pretty lean middleware config.  ThunkMiddleware (not used in graph update actions), a handful of async error & analytics middlewares (commenting them out doesn't noticeably increase performance) and some other middlewares to handle sideeffects like cookies and what not.

Comment: Use the chrome timeline to debug where your bottlenecks are. Redux shouldn't add *that* much overhead--it's almost always updating lots of dom nodes / doing calculations on large arrays. There are some strategies but they come with tradeoffs as well. PIXI.js is something you could use to dramatically increase the number of nodes while keeping the framerate up. another is using `requestIdleCallback` to do heavy calculations between animation frames. then all the typical d3 stuff (reducing selections)

Answer (score 0):

On each tick means `requestAnimationFrame` right? If not, use it. :)

If you are only dispatching one action, meaning one Redux update -> one change callback -> one React re-render, there's not much you can do, your calculations take too much or your React component tree is too big and non efficient (no `shouldComponentUpdate` and so on).

In case you're dispatching more than one action on each frame, you may find useful one technique I've used in the past, which is wrapping my reducer so it can handle an array of actions at once. That way you can avoid re-renders until the last one. The code is surprisingly simple, as everything with Redux is:

```
function withBatching(originalReducer){
   return function(state, action){
      if(action.type === 'BATCH' && Array.isArray(action.payload)){
         return action.payload.reduce(state, originalReducer)
      } else {
         return originalReducer(state, action)
      }
   }
}

//now wrap any (or all) of your reducers
const batchedAppReducer = withBatching(myCombinedAppReducer)
```

In your action creator, instead of dispatching N actions, dispatch one batch of them:

```
{
   type: 'BATCH'
   payload: [
     { type: 'MY_ACTION_TYPE', payload: 'xxxx' },
     { type: 'ANOTHER_THING', payload: 'xxxx' }
   ]
}
```

If you want to batch actions handled by different reducers, I would add batching on your combined reducer, just prior to `createStore`. Otherwise you can simply enable batching for your specific need.

I've used this technique when prototyping some games with great success: in my case I had to update multiple entities at once but didn't want to `render` until the "world" state was updated, so I batched all that updates.

Hope it helps, if you provide some details on your "update" cycle logic I'll try to help you further.

Comment: isn't time to batch update store === time to update every single piece item? I don't understand where the profit is...

Comment: The profit is that React `connect`ed components will update after all actions have been processed, not after each of them. Because Redux calls its subscribers after every dispatch, no matter what have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-redux, there is also a batch API: https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch

From the doc:

```
import { batch } from 'react-redux'

function myThunk() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // should only result in one combined re-render, not two
    batch(() => {
      dispatch(increment())
      dispatch(increment())
    })
  }
}
```